# printf() fixing pointer problems

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I'm trying to write a numerical integrator using a series expansion, however it currently fails on the second step forward in time. This gets fixed if I use printf to print out any of the variables, but I can't find the reason. I've already read many posts about similar scenarios, but none seem to answer my problem. If I print out the value of *t0, *Theta0 and *Theta1 within the function Integrate_One_Step(...), they all have the correct values and show t0, Theta0 and Theta1 to update with each step. Can someone tell me what I'm missing? See the code below.
Thank you.

```
void main()
{
void Integrate_One_Step(double *Theta0, double *Theta1, double *t0, double t_final, double a, double epsilon, double gamma);

int i;
double a,epsilon,gamma,t0,t_final,Theta0,Theta1, tOld;

clock_t tic = clock();

epsilon = 0.1; a = 0.5; gamma = 0.07; t0 = 1e0; tOld = t0; t_final = 10;

Theta0 = 1.753317649649940; Theta1 = 1.759074746790801;

do{
    //printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
    //printf("tstart = %18.15f\n", t0);
    Integrate_One_Step(&Theta0,&Theta1,&t0,t_final,a,epsilon,gamma);
    //printf("tfinish = %18.15f\n", t0);
    //printf("theta = %18.15f\n", Theta0);
    //printf("tOld = %18.15f\n", tOld);
    //printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
    if(t0 <= tOld){
        printf("\nTime Step became zero\n");
        printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
        break;
    }
    else { tOld = t0; }
    if(Theta0 != Theta0){
        printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
        break;
    }
    if(Theta1 != Theta1){
        printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
        break;
    }
} while(t0 < t_final);

clock_t toc = clock();
printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

Edit:
I've posted the full code below for anyone who wishes to try and run it themselves.
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define OrderArray 25
#define HornerOrder 30

    void SeriesMult(double A[], double B[], double C[], int length);
    void Array_Division_By_Constant(double A[],double B[], double constant, int length);
    void Array_Multiply_By_Constant(double A[],double B[], double constant, int length);
    void ArrayAssign(double A[], double B[], int length);
    void Series_Add(double A[],double B[], double C[], int length);

int Time_Steps_Used[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
double Fac[OrderArray],SinFac[HornerOrder],CosFac[HornerOrder],time_step[] = {0.005,0.01,0.03,0.06,0.1,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,0.9,1,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7};

void main()
{
    void Integrate_One_Step(double *Theta0, double *Theta1, double *t0, double t_final, double a, double epsilon, double gamma);

    int i;
    double a,epsilon,gamma,t0,t_final,Theta0,Theta1, tOld;

    clock_t tic = clock();

    epsilon = 0.1; a = 0.5; gamma = 0.07; t0 = 1e0; tOld = t0; t_final = 10;

    //Defines Fac[], SinFac[] and CosFac[] which are arrays of factorials
    Fac[0] = 1e0; SinFac[0] = 1;
    for (i = 1;i<= OrderArray-1;i++)    Fac[i] = i*Fac[i-1];
    for(i=1;i<=HornerOrder-1;i++){ SinFac[i] = -(2*i)*((2*i)+1); }
    for(i=0;i<=HornerOrder-1;i++){ CosFac[i] = -(2*(i+1))*((2*i)+1); }

    Theta0 = 1.753317649649940; Theta1 = 1.759074746790801;

    do{
        //printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
        //printf("tstart = %18.15f\n", t0);
        Integrate_One_Step(&Theta0,&Theta1,&t0,t_final,a,epsilon,gamma);
        //printf("tfinish = %18.15f\n", t0);
        //printf("theta = %18.15f\n", Theta0);
        //printf("tOld = %18.15f\n", tOld);
        //printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
        if(t0 <= tOld){
            printf("\nTime Step became zero\n");
            printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
            break;
        }else{ tOld = t0; }
        if(Theta0 != Theta0){
            printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
            break;
        }
        if(Theta1 != Theta1){
            printf("t = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);
            break;
        }
        //printf("tOld = %18.15f\n", tOld);
    } while(t0 < t_final);

    printf("\n\nt = %18.15f Theta = %18.15f dot_Theta = %18.15f\n", t0, Theta0,Theta1);

    printf("Time steps used: ");
    for(i = 0;i<=17;i++)    printf("%i ",Time_Steps_Used[i]);
    printf("\n\n");

    clock_t toc = clock();
    printf("Elapsed: %f seconds\n", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}

void Integrate_One_Step(double *Theta0, double *Theta1, double *t0, double t_final, double a, double epsilon, double gamma)
{
    double FGH_Nth_Position_Calc(double a, double epsilon, double gamma, double t0, double theta0, double X[], int Position, double dotTheta[], double ddotTheta[]);

    int i,k;
    double Theta[OrderArray],X[OrderArray],dotTheta[OrderArray-1],ddotTheta[OrderArray-2],/*FGH[OrderArray-2],*/    Thet,dotThet,ddotThet,EqnValue,Tol = pow(10,-12), t_inc = 0;

    //printf("At the start of step t = %18.15f \n",*t0);
    Theta[0] = *Theta0; Theta[1] = *Theta1; dotTheta[0] = Theta[1]; ddotTheta[0] = 0;
    X[0] = 0; //X is Theta without the constant term
    for(i=1;i<=OrderArray-1;i++){ X[i] = Theta[i];}

    for(i=0;i<=OrderArray-3;i++){
        //Calculate Theta i+2
        Theta[i+2] = FGH_Nth_Position_Calc(a,epsilon,gamma,(*t0),Theta[0],X,i,dotTheta,ddotTheta);
        //update X
        X[i+2] = Theta[i+2];
        //Update Theta' and Theta''
        dotTheta[i+1] = (i+2)*Theta[i+2];
        //ddotTheta[i] = (i+1)*(i+2)*Theta[i+2]; Slightly more multiplication, unnecessary.
        ddotTheta[i] = (i+1)*dotTheta[i+1];
    }
    //printf("Theta series: ");
    //for(i = 0;i<=OrderArray-1;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",Theta[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");

    //Calculate dotTheta and ddotTheta, then check if the step works
    for(k=0;k<=17;k++){
        ddotThet = 0.0; dotThet = 0.0; Thet = Theta[OrderArray-1];
        if(time_step[k] < (t_final - *t0)){
            for(i = OrderArray-2;i>=0;i--){
                ddotThet = ddotThet*time_step[k] + dotThet; dotThet = dotThet*time_step[k] + Thet; Thet = Thet*time_step[k] + Theta[i];
            }
            ddotThet *= 2e0;
            EqnValue = ddotThet + (((epsilon*sin(*t0+time_step[k]))/(1 + epsilon*cos(*t0+time_step[k])))+gamma)*dotThet + (a/(1 + epsilon*cos(*t0+time_step[k])))*sin(Thet);
            if(fabs(EqnValue) > Tol){ break; 
            }else{ t_inc = time_step[k]; *Theta0 = Thet; *Theta1 = dotThet; if(k>0){Time_Steps_Used[k-1] -= 1;} Time_Steps_Used[k] += 1; }
        }else{
            for(i = OrderArray-2;i>=0;i--){
                ddotThet = ddotThet*(t_final-*t0) + dotThet; dotThet = dotThet*(t_final-*t0) + Thet; Thet = Thet*(t_final-*t0) + Theta[i];
            }
            ddotThet *= 2e0;
            EqnValue = ddotThet + (((epsilon*sin(t_final))/(1 + epsilon*cos(t_final)))+gamma)*dotThet + (a/(1 + epsilon*cos(t_final)))*sin(Thet);
            if(fabs(EqnValue) > Tol){ break; }else{ t_inc = (t_final - *t0); *Theta0 = Thet; *Theta1 = dotThet; }
        }
    }
    //printf("After equation satisfied t0 = %18.15f\n",*t0);
    //printf("t_inc = %18.15f \n",t_inc);
    printf("theta = %18.15f dot_theta = %18.15f\n\n",*Theta0,*Theta1);
    //Add time step to t0
    *t0 = *t0 + t_inc;
    //printf("After incremented t = %18.15f\n",*t0);
}

double FGH_Nth_Position_Calc(double a, double epsilon, double gamma, double t0, double theta0, double X[], int Position, double dotTheta[], double ddotTheta[])
{
    void CosT_Calc(double coss[], double t0, int length);
    void FCalc(double epsilon, double Cost[], double ddotTheta[], double F[], int length);
    void HCalc(double a, double X[], double H[], double theta0, int Position);
    void GCalc(double epsilon, double gamma, double t0, double Cost[], double G[], double dotTheta[], int Position);

    int i;
    double F[Position+1],H[Position+1],G[Position+1],Cost[Position+1],FGH[Position+1],Divider;

    //for(i = 0;i<=Position;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",dotTheta[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");
    //for(i = 0;i<=Position;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",ddotTheta[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");
    //for(i = 0;i<=Position;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",ddotTheta2[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");

    //Calculates coefficicients of cos(t) where t is the total time after the step is taken.
    CosT_Calc(Cost,t0,Position+1);
    //for(i=0;i<=Position;i++)  printf("%18.15f ",Cost[i]); printf("\n");

    //Calculates F = epsilon*cos(t - t0)* \theta''
    FCalc(epsilon,Cost, ddotTheta, F, Position);
    //for(i = 0;i<=Position;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",F[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");
    //Calculates G = [epsilon*sin(t) + gamma*(1+epsilon*cos(t)) ]*theta'
    GCalc(epsilon,gamma,t0,Cost,G,dotTheta,Position);
    //for(i = 0;i<=Position;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",G[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");
    //Calculates H = a*sin(Theta)
    HCalc(a,X, H,theta0,Position);
    //for(i = 0;i<=Position;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",H[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");

    Series_Add(F,G,FGH,Position+1);
    Series_Add(FGH,H,FGH,Position+1);
    Divider = (Position+1)*(Position+2)*(1+epsilon*cos(t0)); //printf("Divider = %18.15f\n",Divider);
    Array_Division_By_Constant(FGH,FGH,Divider, Position+1);
    return(-FGH[Position]);
}

void GCalc(double epsilon, double gamma, double t0, double Cost[], double G[], double dotTheta[], int Position)
{
    void SinT_Calc(double Sinn[], double t0, int length);

    int i;
    double Sint[Position+1],epsilSint[Position+1],epsilCostPlusOne[Position+1],g[Position+1];

    //Calculates sin(t)
    SinT_Calc(Sint,t0,Position+1);
    //printf("Sin(t) series");
    //for(i=0;i<=Position;i++)  printf("%18.15f ",Sint[i]); printf("\n");
    //multiplies sin(t) and cos(t) by epsilon
    Array_Multiply_By_Constant(epsilSint,Sint,epsilon,Position+1);
    Array_Multiply_By_Constant(epsilCostPlusOne,Cost,epsilon,Position+1);
    //Calculates gamma*(1 + epsilon*cos(t))
    epsilCostPlusOne[0] = epsilCostPlusOne[0]+1;
    Array_Multiply_By_Constant(epsilCostPlusOne,epsilCostPlusOne,gamma,Position+1);
    //Calculates g = [epsilon*sin(t) + gamma*(1+epsilon*cos(t)) ]
    Series_Add(epsilSint,epsilCostPlusOne,g,Position+1); //This appears to be correct when comparing with maple
    //for(i = 0;i<=Position;i++)    printf("%18.15f ",g[i]);
    //printf("\n\n");
    //Multiples g by theta'
    SeriesMult(g,dotTheta,G,Position+1);

}

void HCalc(double a, double X[], double H[], double theta0, int Position)
{
    void SinTheta_Calc(double CosX[], double SinX[], double SinTheta[], double theta0, int length);
    void CosX_Calc(double Xsquared[], double CosTemp[], int length);
    void SinX_Calc(double X[], double Xsquared[], double Sinn[], int length);
    double NthTerm(double A[], double B[], int n, int sizeA, int sizeB);

    int i;
    double Xsquared[Position+1],CosX[Position+1],SinX[Position+1],SinTheta[Position+1];
    //Calculates Xsquared
    for(i=0;i<=Position;i++){
        Xsquared[i] = NthTerm(X,X,i,Position,Position);
    }
    //Calulate Cos(X), Sin(X)
    CosX_Calc(Xsquared,CosX,Position+1); SinX_Calc(X,Xsquared,SinX,Position+1);
    //Calculate Sin(Theta) from Sin(X) and Cos(X)
    SinTheta_Calc(CosX,SinX,SinTheta,theta0, Position+1);
    //H = a*SinTheta
    Array_Multiply_By_Constant(H,SinTheta, a, Position+1);

}

void SinTheta_Calc(double CosX[], double SinX[], double SinTheta[], double theta0, int length)
{
    int i;
    double CosXTemp[length],SinXTemp[length], S_Theta0, C_Theta0;
    S_Theta0 = sin(theta0); C_Theta0 = cos(theta0);
    Array_Multiply_By_Constant(SinXTemp,SinX,C_Theta0,length);
    Array_Multiply_By_Constant(CosXTemp,CosX,S_Theta0,length);
    Series_Add(CosXTemp,SinXTemp,SinTheta,length);
}

void CosX_Calc(double Xsquared[], double CosTemp[], int length)
{
    //Calculates Cos(X) where X is the series for Theta, without the constant term, outputs the final series for Cos(X) as CosTemp
    int i,j,SubHornerOrder;
    double Xsquared_divided[length], Coss[length];

    if(length == 0){SubHornerOrder = 1; }
    else if(length%2 == 0) {SubHornerOrder = length/2; }
    else {SubHornerOrder = (length+1)/2; }

    Array_Division_By_Constant(CosTemp,Xsquared,CosFac[SubHornerOrder-1],length);
    CosTemp[0] = 1;
    for(i=(SubHornerOrder-1);i>=1;i--){
        Array_Division_By_Constant(Xsquared_divided,Xsquared,CosFac[i-1],length);
        SeriesMult(Xsquared_divided, CosTemp, Coss, length);
        ArrayAssign(CosTemp, Coss, length);
        CosTemp[0] = 1;
    }
}



void SinX_Calc(double X[], double Xsquared[], double Sinn[], int length)
{
    //Calculate Sin(X) where X is the series for Theta, without the constant term, outputs the final series for Sin(X) as Sinn
    int i,j, SubHornerOrder;
    double Xsquared_divided[length], SinTemp[length];

    if(length == 0){SubHornerOrder = 1; }
    else if(length%2 == 0) {SubHornerOrder = length/2; }
    else {SubHornerOrder = (length+1)/2; }

    Array_Division_By_Constant(SinTemp,Xsquared,SinFac[SubHornerOrder-1],length);
    SinTemp[0] = 1;
    for(i=(SubHornerOrder-1);i>=2;i--){
        Array_Division_By_Constant(Xsquared_divided,Xsquared,SinFac[i-1],length);
        SeriesMult(Xsquared_divided, SinTemp, Sinn, length);
        ArrayAssign(SinTemp, Sinn, length);
        SinTemp[0] = 1;
    }
    SeriesMult(X,SinTemp,Sinn,length);
}

void FCalc(double epsilon, double Cost[], double ddotTheta[], double F[], int Position)
{
    double epsilCost[Position+1];
    //multiplies Cos(t) by epsilon
    Array_Multiply_By_Constant(epsilCost,Cost,epsilon,Position+1);
    //Calculates F = epsilon*cos(t - t0)* \theta''
    SeriesMult(epsilCost, ddotTheta, F, Position+1);
}

void SinT_Calc(double sinn[], double t0, int length)
{ // Sets up Taylor series coefficients for sin(t) = cos(t0)sin(t-t0) + sin(t0)cos(t-t0)
    int i;
    double  st0, ct0;
    int m1n(int i);

    st0 = sin(t0); ct0 = cos(t0);

    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
            sinn[i] = st0*m1n(i/2)/Fac[i];
        else
            sinn[i] = ct0*m1n((i-1)/2)/Fac[i];
    }
}

void CosT_Calc(double coss[], double t0, int length)
{ // Sets up Taylor series coefficients for cos(t) = cos(t0)cos(t-t0) - sin(t0)sin(t-t0)
    int i;
    double  st0, ct0;
    int m1n(int i);

    st0 = sin(t0); ct0 = cos(t0);

    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
            coss[i] = ct0*m1n(i/2)/Fac[i];
        else
            coss[i] = -st0*m1n((i-1)/2)/Fac[i];
    }
}

int m1n(int i)
{
    if (i%2 == 0)   return(1);
    else        return(-1);
}

double NthTerm(double A[], double B[], int n, int sizeA, int sizeB)
{
    //Multiplies returns the n-th term when 2 arrays are multiplied
    double nth_term = 0;
    int j;
    for(j=0; j <= n;j++){
        if (j < sizeA){
            if ( (n-j)< sizeB){
                nth_term += A[j]*B[n-j];
            }
        }
    }
    return(nth_term);
}

void Series_Add(double A[],double B[], double C[], int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=length-1;i++){
        C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    }
}

void SeriesMult(double A[], double B[], double C[], int length)
{
    //Multiplies two arrays, returns nothing but stores the answer in the array C
    int i, j;
    double c;
    for(i=0; i<=length-1; i++){
        c = 0;
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++){
            c = c + A[j]*B[i-j];
        }
        C[i] = c;
    }
}

void Array_Multiply_By_Constant(double A[],double B[], double constant, int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=length-1;i++){
        A[i] = B[i]*constant;
    }
}

void Array_Division_By_Constant(double A[],double B[], double constant, int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=length-1;i++){
        A[i] = B[i]/constant;
    }
}

void ArrayAssign(double A[], double B[], int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=length-1;i++){
        A[i] = B[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `valgrind` to debug pointer problems. The fact that `printf` "fixes" is it just an accident because memory layout is changing.

Comment: What's up with `if (Theta0 != Theta0)` checks?

Comment: I should also mention, I've run valgrind which found no errors, so I don't think the problem originates from over stepping any array sizes.

Comment: the `if(Theta0 != Theta0)` checks are making sure I haven't for some reason got inf or NaN values for my Theta variables.

Comment: Why not use `isnan()`?

Comment: I could equally use `isnan()` but then I'd also need to use `isinf()` , this way I can check both at once. Though I don't think checking this way is the source of the problem.

Comment: Do you know which line it crashes on?

Comment: The code runs, but fails the test `if(t0 <= tOld)` . For some reason, if printf() is not called the function `Integrate_One_Step(...)` cannot make a time step forward, so `t0` does not increase in comparison with `tOld`. However if I call `printf()` in the code you see, the integrator makes several time steps and `t0` eventually reaches the final value of time.

Comment: I don't see a problem in this code.  Perhaps there is a bug inside the integrator function that does some random damage on the stack, and when you insert calls to printf, the layout of the stack changes.  I'm assuming the integrating function is huge and it is not a good candidate for posting here?

Comment: If you don't have a good debugger handy, sprinkle a few printfs around the integrator function that would trace the value of t0 (even in places where it is ostensibly not modified).  That should give you a better idea of where the value of the variable goes haywire.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately your assumption is correct. Of course I would be happy to make all of the code available if you wanted to copy it to run yourself, but I thought that might be considered uncouth.

Comment: If you could post the code somewhere (offsite if needed), that would be helpful, as I don't see a bug in the snippet above with my "eagle" eyes.

Comment: I've now added the full code. Thank you for your determination to help.

Comment: Please discard whatever book told you to use `void main()`, and change it to `int main(void)`. You use the name `Theta0` both for a `double*` parameter and for a `double` object, which is legal but confusing. The declaration of `Time_Steps_Used` can be more concisely written as `int Time_Steps_Used[19] = {0};`. (None of this addresses your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have buffer overflow errors in places such as:

```
void SinT_Calc(double sinn[], double t0, int length)
{ // Sets up Taylor series coefficients for sin(t) = cos(t0)sin(t-t0) + sin(t0)cos(t-t0)
    int i;
    double  st0, ct0;
    int m1n(int i);

    st0 = sin(t0); ct0 = cos(t0);

    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) // <=== BUFFER OVERFLOW, should be strict <
    {
        if (i%2 == 0)
            sinn[i] = st0*m1n(i/2)/Fac[i];
        else
            sinn[i] = ct0*m1n((i-1)/2)/Fac[i];
    }
}
```

If I had one other unrelated piece of advice, it would be to never use dynamically sized arrays on the stack (actually, it's surprising this even compiles):

```
double Xsquared[Position+1];
```

Instead use

```
double* Xsquared = (double*)malloc((Position + 1) * sizeof(double));
//...
free(Xsquared);
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this is definitely helpful. I was unaware that `Xsquared[Position+1]` was dynamically sized. Does it not automatically free when the function finishes?

Comment: There is no need to free when you declare an array with `Xsquared[Position+1]`, because it is allocated on the stack (`free()` is only needed if you `malloc()` first).  The problem is different.  "Dynamically-sized" means that the size of the array is determined at runtime based on a variable (in this case, a function argument).  This is problematic, because stack memory is usually limited in size and cannot grow on demand.  As a result, if you pass in 1000000 or some other large number as the size, you will produce a stack overflow.

Comment: The array sizing issue is of secondary importance though.  Do you understand the primary bug with the buffer overflow and how to fix it?  Or should I add more explanation to the answer.

Comment: I understand where the functions `SinT_Calc` and `CosT_Calc` overflowed and how this could cause problems, however having fixed these I still have the original problem. If you've managed to solve that I'd appreciate if you could add more explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you're still seeing an issue where if you add printfs, it works, but if you don't, it doesn't?  I can't identify any more memory corruption.  It should at least be behaving consistently now.

Comment: Yes, unless I "fixed" the problem incorrectly. I changed `for (i = 0; i <= length; i++)` to `for (i = 0; i <= length-1; i++)` . I think this should have solved the issue.

Comment: No, that fix should work.  Unfortunately I can't find any other significant issues in a surface inspection, and the code runs fine locally (I had to change `pow(10,-12)` to `pow((double)10,-12)` to avoid a local compilation error).  In my setup, commenting out printfs vs leaving them in has no effect on execution.

Comment: Perhaps it's the compiler then, I'm using gcc with linux, though I didn't think the code should run differently after compiled. Using `valgrind -v --track-origins=yes` I find my code has several errors relating to an uninitialised value created by a stack allocation, but I can't find where in the code this is.

Comment: I used MSVC compiler for Windows.  If you're sure that you have problems with uninitialized variables, there is an straightforward fix: initialize all variables where they are defined, and memset all allocations (or use `calloc()` instead of` malloc()`).  It's good practice to do this for all C/C++ code.

Comment: I've now fixed the program by initialising `Theta[OrderArray] = {0}`, `dotTheta[OrderArray-1] = {0}` and `ddotTheta[OrderArray-2] = {0}` , The problem was a result of ddotTheta` being iteratively defined and the code trying to access an element before it was defined. Thanks for all the advice.